# How to add a placeholder curly braces in dictionary keys

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

So, I have a dictionary like below:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("first", "Value1");
dict.Add("second", "Value2");
```

And I have a string like below:

```
rawMsg = "My values are {first} and {second}.";
```

**Output expected:**

```
My values are Value1 and Value2.
```

String Formating Code:

```
public void Format(string rawMsg, Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    var temp = dict.Aggregate(rawMsg, (current, parameter) => current.Replace(parameter.Key, parameter.Value.ToString())); 
}
```

For above code to work, I need to add keys as below:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("{first}", "Value1"); // Notice the curly braces in Keys
dict.Add("{second}", "Value2");
```

**But I don't want to add curly braces in the key.**

I want to append curly braces in my **format** Logic.

Pseudo code:

```
public void Format(string rawMsg, Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    // loop through all the keys and append a curly braces in them.
    var temp = dict.Aggregate(rawMsg, (current, parameter) => current.Replace(parameter.Key, parameter.Value.ToString())); 
}
```

But I am don't know an efficient way to do it. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it when you need it?

```
public void Format(string rawMsg, Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    var temp = dict.Aggregate(rawMsg, (current, parameter) => current.Replace("{" + parameter.Key + "}", parameter.Value.ToString())); 
}
```

Comment: @Unbreakable Note that if you're looking for an "efficient" way to do this, this solution (while working) might not be the best choice since for each key, it does 2 string concatenations and the whole string is scanned for candidate replacements. Solutions based on regular expressions (like Dmitry Bychenko's) will perform better especially if there are many items in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating your own *string interpolation*, I suggest *regular expressions*, e.g.:

```
  Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    {"first", "Value1" },
    {"second", "Value2" },
  };

  string rawMsg = "My values are {first} and {second}.";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
    rawMsg, 
   @"\{[^{}]+?\}", 
    match => dict[match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 2)]?.ToString());

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  My values are Value1 and Value2.
```

**P.S.** I've assumed that you want to make all changes in *one go* i.e. for

```
  Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    {"first", "{second}" },
    {"second", "third" },
  };

  string rawMsg = "My values are {{first}} and {second}.";
```

The right answer is

```
  My values are {second} and third.
```

Not (we don't want to process `second` *twice*)

```
  My values are third and third.
```

Comment: I believe OP wants the outcome to be without the curly braces characters. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @vinicius.ras: Thank you! I've edited both my answer and the question (highlighted the desired result)

Comment: I think this solution is more efficient than the accepted solution which involves multiple string concatenations and calls to `string.Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. In short, creating a regex and storing it in a static member to compile only once and then using it to replace place holder occurrences with their value in string ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PMOxia)).

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"(?<={)(\w+)");

...

public string Format(string rawMsg, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> dict) =>

    _regex.Replace(rawMsg, match =>
    {
        string placeHolder = match.ToString();

        return dict.TryGetValue(placeHolder, out object placeHolderValue) 
                   ? placeHolderValue.ToString() : null;
    });
```

Note that the first regex group is non capturing to exclude the curly braces from the captures.